# Train with custom weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Currently I am using transfer learning to train a neural network.
I am using the ResNet50 pretrained model provided by keras.

```
base_model=ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# function to finetune model
def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    for fc in fc_layers:
        # New FC layer, random init
        x = Dense(fc, use_bias=False)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    # New softmax layer
    x = Dense(num_classes, use_bias=False)(x) 
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    predictions = Activation('softmax')(x)
    finetune_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

    return finetune_model

FC_LAYERS = [1024, 512]
dropout = 0.5

model = build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout=dropout, fc_layers=FC_LAYERS,num_classes=len(categories))
```

Now I wanted to see whether or not using [Resnet50 1by2](https://github.com/jay-mahadeokar/pynetbuilder/tree/master/models/imagenet) (amongst others) would increase my accuracy. These models are provided as caffe models. I used the [Caffe weight converter](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/caffe_weight_converter) to convert these models to a keras h5 file.

The problem now is that these files do not contain a model that can be trained, only the weights.
How can I use the weights to train a model in keras?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have saved weights, you can only load those weights into a network with the same architecture. Assuming the weights you have match the architecture of the Keras Applications model, you can:

```
base_model = ResNet50(...,weights=None)
base_model.load_weights('my_weights_file.h5')
for layer in base_model.layers:
   layer.training = False
```

Comment: According to the description of the 1by2 Resnet50 model: "Similar to resnet 50 in paper, blocks:[3,4,6,3] all layers have half filters except conv1". These should be differences inside the model itself. Does it still work then? Also when I tried this, I got an error saying that the ResNet50 model had 106 layers but my weights had 107.

Comment: Hmm. It might be close. Perhaps you can figure out the missing layer and add it. It's almost definitely the first or last; my bet is that it's the final global pooling layer, on the end. A quick way to try it would be adding `pooling='avg'` or `'max'` to the `ResNet50()` call. Otherwise you might have to go hunting.